# Sphinx renders :ref: with italics -- How can I remove this?

Tags: restructuredtext

I have two different pages where one links to the other for example:

file 1

```
.. _create-title:

How to create a title
-----------------------
```

file 2

```
to :ref:`create <create-title>` a title ....
```

Sphinx renders this to

```
<em>create</em>
```

Comment: Did you see any warning or error messages? It looks like the underline does not match the length of the text of the heading. Try matching their lengths.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when I do this instead:

```
.. _create_title:
```

Sphinx will not render the text into italics:

```
to :ref:`create <create_title>` a title ....
```